# connexion between FB app and FB messenger

Tags: ios, facebook, sandbox

my question is simple, how FB messenger know who is connected with the other FB app, i mean that in ios, apps use sandBox but when you are connected in the 'normal' app as 'xy' and you open the messenger one it ask you if you are xy ? and if you disconnect from the 'normal' app and you open the other again it ask you to connect. how those apps are connected together ?
thank you.

Comment: FB stores your device number UUID and links it to an account server-side.  It's a simple query after that.

Comment: i don't think so. let me explain: if i connect in normal app, messenger cant ( or don't want ? ) ask who I'm.
i try other thing, i connect in normal app as 'xy', disconnect from messenger, disconnect from internet, close the 2 apps and when i open messenger it ask me if im 'xy'?! so i think is not in server side right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two apps from the same developer can access the same keychain group.

> The main pre-requisite for shared keychain access is that all of the applications have a common bundle seed ID.

More information can be found for example [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html).